# xcodebuild - how to specify the directory where the project is, without doing a cd in it

Tags: macos, xcodebuild

I am using xcodebuild from command line in a script, but I realized that I cannot specify the path of the project that i wanna build;I am forced to cd in the folder where the project is.

Is there a way to accomplish the build process without having to cd in the directory, or this is how it must be?

Is not a big deal to cd into the directory and execute xcodebuild, but I wonder what if someday you need to build a project and you cannot cd into the directory....It doesn't really make sense to me to not being able to specify the path.

Comment: I don’t really get the ‘you cannot cd into the directory’ part. What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you can't cd into the directory, I think you've got more immediate problems than xcodebuild.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *must* be in the directory containing the project(s) when you run `xcodebuild`. If you don’t want to mess with your current directory, there a couple of options:

```
/bin/sh -c "cd $PRJDIR; xcodebuild"
```

or

```
(cd $PRJDIR; xcodebuild)
```

Comment: You could also try using `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`.

Comment: @splicer Nice. I didn't know about those.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! So indeed is not possible to do it without being in the directory where the project lives, but i can use these solutions that you mentioned!

Comment: Use `-project` to specify path.

Answer (score 27):

You can use xcodebuild **-project pathtoprojectfile**

eg

xcodebuild -project  /IOSprojects/YourProject/YourProject.xcodeproj